# Google Hybrid OpenID+OAuth with dotnetopenauth

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth, google-openid, google-oauth

I have spent probably more than 10 hours in the last two days trying to understand how to implement user login with Google Hybrid OpenID+OAuth ([Federated Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=vi-VN#oauth))

To trigger the authorization request I use:

```
InMemoryOAuthTokenManager tm = new InMemoryOAuthTokenManager( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerSecret"]);
using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
{
  Realm realm = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerKey"] + "/";
  IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(identifier, Realm.AutoDetect, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + "/OAuth/google"));

  var authorizationRequest = new AuthorizationRequest
  {
    Consumer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerKey"],
    Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
  };

  request.AddExtension(authorizationRequest);

  request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest
  {
    Email = DemandLevel.Request,
    Gender = DemandLevel.Require
  });

  request.RedirectToProvider();
}
```

To retrieve the accesstoken I use:

```
using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
{
  IAuthenticationResponse authResponse = openid.GetResponse();
  if (authResponse != null)
  {
    switch (authResponse.Status)
    {
      case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
        HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("AuthenticationStatus", "Authenticated");
        FetchResponse fr = authResponse.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();

        InMemoryOAuthTokenManager tm = new InMemoryOAuthTokenManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerSecret"]);

        ServiceProviderDescription spd = new ServiceProviderDescription {
          spd.RequestTokenEndpoint = new DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
          spd.AccessTokenEndpoint = new DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
          spd.UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline", HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
          spd.TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() };

        WebConsumer wc = new WebConsumer(spd, tm);
        AuthorizedTokenResponse accessToken = wc.ProcessUserAuthorization();

        if (accessToken != null)
        {
          HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("accessToken", accessToken.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
        }
        break;
      case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
        HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("AuthenticationStatus", "Canceled");
        break;
      case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
        HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("AuthenticationStatus", "Failed");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly I get `AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated` but `wc.ProcessUserAuthorization()` is `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `WebConsumer`, use the `WebConsumerOpenIdRelyingParty` class, which is available in the [DotNetOpenAuth.OpenIdOAuth](http://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.OpenIdOAuth) NuGet package.  This class provides the helper methods for attaching the OAuth request as an OpenID extension (which you did pretty well for yourself anyway) and for extracting the OpenID extension response on the way back.

Looking at [the source code for the above mentioned class](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.OpenIdOAuth/OAuth/WebConsumerOpenIdRelyingParty.cs) may help inspire you.  There is also a sample specifically of Google OpenID login plus OAuth extension in DotNetOpenAuth.  [Get the samples from SourceForge](http://sf.net/projects/dnoa/), then look in the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms sample project's loginPlusOAuth.aspx page (and code-behind, and supporting classes).